# ESP32 OTA without flashing code to the device

Tags: esp32, ota

So I'm trying to implement an OTA way to update like 100's of devices at the same time. Now, I have googled alot aready and always saw that you have a webserver running and upload a .bin file on the device itself, then flash this file to the device.

That's OK, if you only have 1-5 devices, not when you have 100's of edge devices that you like no way have to access those physically and/or via an local IP (since they are all over the country).

They do have all internet access and communicate to a server via MQTT, but we can also do some API calls.

The main goal I want to achieve is the following:

ESP boots with some flashed "bootloader" that visits a pre-defined server address in the bootloader.
The response is the binary file the edge device should run.
The binary file gets loaded into the device it's RAM (or if needed, an SD-card or some sort of other flash memory).
When the binary is downloaded, it gets executed **NOT FLASHED ONTO THE DEVICE**. I want to have when I take the device and want to reverse engineer the binar that I can only reverse engineer the bootloader, not the main code that would get pulled from the server.

The main questions are thus;

- Is this even possible? (I am making a custom board, so that can have alot of special components on it if needed)
- How should I do this? I can't figure out at all how this goes then
- am I missing anything?

Thanks!

Comment: So what happens when the device loses power? What does it run when it restarts?

Comment: When the device looses power, then all the code pulled from the server should be gone. when you give the device back it's power, it needs to re-download it's binary and execute

Comment: if you want to protect your code, then you just have to encrypt the flash, esp32 has already tools available for this. Otherwise you will have to implement all this functionality yourself.

Answer (score 2):

The ESP32 can execute code from its [instruction RAM](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/api-guides/general-notes.html#iram-instruction-ram) - should be possible to do whatever you want with the limitation that you can use up to 128 KiB (+32 KiB if running single-core) of it for your application code. See [this article](https://medium.com/the-esp-journal/esp32-programmers-memory-model-259444d89387#:%7E:text=The%20192%20KB%20of%20available,flash%20(and%20PSRAM)%20access.) for a programmer-friendly description of the memory model. However, that's going to suffice for firmware with simple functionality, but stuff like MQTT over TLS will be *hard* to fit in 160 KiB of code.

Also note that the ESP IDF does not have support for such extravaganza, so you'll be writing *a lot* of low-level code starting with your own custom linker scripts and C runtime initialization. If you're prepared and budgeted for that, go ahead - it'll be a fun and challenging project.

Otherwise I'd recommend evaluating Espressif's solution for protecting code in the Flash memory from being read out. You can [encrypt](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/security/flash-encryption.html) the entire Flash using AES256 (everything gets decrypted on the fly), combined with [Secure Boot V2](https://docs.espressif.com/projects/esp-idf/en/latest/esp32/security/secure-boot-v2.html) to make sure only approved images can run. There are vulnerabilities in either approach, but this way you'll likely be finished with your product an order of magnitude faster.

As for doing OTA for 100 devices - with a few lines of server side code you can use your MQTT connection to issue an update trigger command to all of them at once. It makes no difference how the OTA is implemented - they'll all be happy to download the new image and update themselves in parallel.

Comment: So I make out of this: That is not possible?
I even ask myself if it is possible to read out the .bin that was flashed onto an esp?

Comment: Running an app from RAM is possible (if you have what it takes), but not practical in most cases. As for reading out the .bin in Flash, this has two aspects. The SPI Flash and the microcontroller are separate chips and the SPI bus between them is open to physical access, meaning you can always read the content of the Flash with little effort. However, if you encrypt the content of the Flash, this will be useless without the decryption key which is hidden inside the microcontroller. That's *much* harder to break open (not impossible, like all non-hardened protection mechanisms, just difficult).